# Kitchen test failed: Sudo requires a password, please configure it on default-centos-67

Tags: chef-infra, sudo, chef-recipe, cookbook, test-kitchen

This is content of **default.rb** recipe of my cookbook.

```
include_recipe 'sudo'
include_recipe 'chef-vault'

group "#{node['cookbook']['group']}" do 
  action    :create
  append    true
  system    false
end

user 'user' do
    supports    :manage_home => false 
    home        nil
    system      false
    password    "HASH_PASSWORD"
    gid         "#{node['cookbook']['group']}"
    shell       '/bin/bash'
    action      :create
end
```

This is also the content of kitchen.yml.

```
    driver:
      name: docker
      use_sudo: false

    provisioner:
      name: chef_zero

    verifier:
      name: inspec

    platforms:
      - name: centos-6.7

    suites:
     - name: default
       data_bags_path: "test/integration/default/data_bags"
       encrypted_data_bag_secret_key_path: "test/integration/default/encrypted_data_bag_secret"
       run_list:
        - recipe[rise-users::default]
       attributes:
```

This is the kitchen test that I created.

```
control "mycookbook-1.0" do
   impact 1.0
   title "myCookbook users packages and configuration files"
   desc "packages and configuration files that should exist on all  servers"

   describe user('user') do
     it { should exist }
   end
end
```

I executed the **kitchen test** command and got this eror.

```
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
>>>>>> Message: 1 actions failed.
>>>>>>     Failed to complete #verify action: [Sudo failed: Sudo requires a password, please configure it.] on default-centos-67
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration
```

I updated the **kitchen.yml** just to configure it since sudo requires a password but unfortunately it doesn't work.

I fixed it by updating the`attributes` in `kitchen.yml`.

```
 attributes: 
    authorization: 
        sudo: 
            users: ['kitchen'] 
            passwordless: true 
            include_sudoers_d: true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually means somewhere in a cookbook you are testing, you are changing the sudoers config such that the `kitchen` user doesn't have nopasswd sudo. You need to either not do that, or when running under Test Kitchen make sure you re-create the entry for the `kitchen` user.

Comment: hi @coderanger, I didn't override any attributes or sudoers config of `sudo` cookbook but the problem exists when I include it in my cookbook. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Yes, the default config of the `sudo` cookbook is enough to break things.

Comment: hi @coderanger, I agree with you. I created a temporary solution by logging-in the virtual machine using `kitchen login` and edit the `sudoers` file just to add the kitchen user. how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: hi @coderanger, I fixed it by adding this configuration in `kitchen.yml`. I added above on how to fix it. Thanks.